# Is it possible to send a custom text message to a Windows Form and receive a custom text response?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ipc

I want to know if it's possible to do that or if the only messages that you can pass to a window consist of predefined message that command the window to do something.

If it's possible to pass it text and receive more text in response, can someone write a small piece of code showing me how to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Would WCF, .net Remoting/Named Pipes work?

Comment: Are you talking about PostMessage (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: unfortunately plain old remoting is not an option and I couldn't get wcf's named pipes to work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your custom message codes in Windows and send them. Note that when you send a message across the process boundaries, only WM_COPYDATA message can carry other data besides two DWORDs (wParam and lParam): only for WM_COPYDATA windows does data marshalling.

Writing the code is not an option on StackOverflow - use Google search.